# Extending line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

Suppose you have a one parameter family of algebraic varieties over unit disk, such that the central fiber is singular and is a union (normal-crossing) of two varieties and the rest are smooth.

Is it true that every line bundle over a smooth fiber, after some base-change, extends to the whole family? Do you know any counter example?

This is the true (although not very obvious) for a family of curves, since line bundles are just bunch of points.

Extra assumption: $h^{2,0}=0$ for the smooth fibers, and they are simply connected, so that the ample cone does not move within $H^2$.

Answer (score 5):

This is not even true when all fibers are smooth. For example, see Example 5.22 in Kleiman's paper on the Picard scheme in "FGA explained".

Comment: I dont have access to the book, can you recall what the example is.
In the setting I have, this is true for the smooth ones. So may be i need to put some restrictions on my family. 

I will edit my question then.


Comment: Mohammad: see http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504020.pdf